# Orbeon Thread starvation or clock leap detected on Liferay 7.0

Tags: orbeon, liferay-7, liferay-ide

we have an issue when we are trying to intgrate the [orbeon proxy portlet](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/linking-and-embedding/liferay-proxy-portlet) in our liferay 7.0 distribution.
As fas as I know, we have to include the license.xml into the "WEB-INF/resources/config" inside the .war file.
After this, I deployed the .war file into the "deploy" folder under our "budles" folder but out tomcat server freezes and after a while we are starting to get messages like this:

```
11:07:39,304 WARN  [HikariPool-2 housekeeper][HikariPool:676] HikariPool-2 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=50s936ms528Âµs270ns).

11:07:50,174 WARN  [HikariPool-1 housekeeper][HikariPool:676] HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=45s279ms904Âµs144ns).
```

What I'm doing wrong? Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The license file goes into the WAR file of Form Runner, but not into the proxy portlet WAR file. Either way, I don't know what that "Thread starvation or clock leap detected" means, I have never seen that message. Does Form Runner standalone work for you?

Comment: Just to say that the problem was only that the .war file of the orbeon don't should be deployed on the "deploy" folder of Liferay, but decompressed into the Tomcat server/webapps folder and then deploy the proxy-portlet.

I know it's trivial and is explained on the tutorial, but maybe it could be usefull for someone new on Liferay like me with the same problem.